# greenDao 2.1.0 / 2.0.0, query with chained joins

Tags: android, join, greendao

I created a n:m relation between entities A and C using a join B.
Each entity C has a parameter p, and I want to query the list of entities A using conditions on the values taken by the p of the different Cs that are linked to the  A.
It looks like this :

> A {_id} <-- B {_id, A_id, C_id} --> C {_id, p}

Where my As are linked to Many Bs, each B beeing linked to a single C 
 (also  many Bs can link to the same C, but I think it's not relevant here).

What I want is, for example, all the As that are : 
linked to a C where p = x AND linked to another C where p = y 
OR
linked to a C where p =z

I've built up the Chained Joins to access the p property in C, but it looks like a dead-end has I just seem to be able to give one (or many) condition that a single C should match, and not single conditions that need to be matched by different Cs. What I have look like this :

```
QueryBuilder<A> queryA = aDao.queryBuilder();
Join joinAB = queryA.join(B.class, BDao.Properties.A_Id);
Join joinBC = queryA.join(joinAB, BDao.Properties.C_Id, C.class, CDAo.Properties.Id);
```

If I go on with p=z :

```
joinBC.where(CDao.Properties.p.eq("z");
List<A> listA = queryA.list();
```

This give me the list of As that are linked to a C where p = z.

But how do I manage the other condition, being : linked to a C where p = x AND linked to another C where p = y ?